# Puting two or more GLfloats[] arrays into an NSArray cant i get bad exe_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, xcode

i have a group of GLfloat C [] arrays that i wamt to put in an NSMutableArray and i get a pointer waning when i try adding one but it works but when i try putting more then one it crashes when i try to add them in

```
 static GLfloat uvsForMan[8] = {0.0, 0.95, 0.12, 0.95, 0.0, 0.2, 0.12, 0.2};


 static GLfloat uvsForManB[8] = {0.12, 0.95, 0.27, 0.95, 0.12, 0.2, 0.39, 0.2};



    NSMutableArray *gh = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects: uvsForMan, uvsForManB, nil];
```

i do not dynamically allocate memory for these do i have to or do i have to wrap then in an object class and i tried NSNumber but was unsuccessful  and how do i do these

i also have a method that takes a Mutable array as an argument and opens it to get the GLfloat values and it works when i put one GLfloat array in but when i try adding the second it gives me EXE_BAD_ACCESS

```
 MoleculeCharged  *rightButton = [[MoleculeCharged alloc]initWithAtlas:@"legs1d" 
                    uvspriteMArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:uvsForMan]
                                                          materialKey:@"legs1d"];


      rightButton.tranlation = BBPointMake(-100.0, -50.0, 0.0);

         rightButton.scale = BBPointMake(80, 200, 1.0);
```

Help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `NSMutableArray` is only able to store instances of classes which are derived from `NSObject`. It wont accept primitive data-types. You either need to wrap your `CGFloat` with an `NSNumber` or just use the static allocated c-array.

Comment: OK as i suspected , thank you quick answer too                              Any advice on what would be the best way to wrap them and and put them in the array

Comment: If you want to use `NS(Mutable)Array` you should wrap them with `NSNumber`. Or rewrite your code so that it is able to use c-arrays. Because of your array is static you could also implement the adapter-pattern to your array in combination with the singleton-pattern. The "user" then uses sth like `[[MyPreferences sharedPreferences] getElementAtIndex:3]`